# How to prevent title attribute from showing tooltip?

Tags: html, attributes, popup, tooltip, title

I'm developing a web app using Angular and Semantic-UI.
I'm using Semantic-UI's Popup to show stylish tooltips when users hover some elements.
Anyway I have to add `title` attribute to be compliant with A11Y (WCAG 2.0) and to make screen readers to read the text content of `title` attribute.

As you can figure out in this way I get double tooltips for some elements.

Do you know a way to make `title` attribute to keep text and to stop it from displaying popup?

I don't want remove the text so I can't use `removeAttr` method provided by jQuery...

Comment: Can't you just change Semantic-UI's Popup function that currently binds to the title attribute to bind to another attribute like semantic-title?

Comment: Semantic-UI's Popup function doesn't bind to the title attribute. Anyway this would not solve the problem, because the title attribute is still there to show.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no way to disable the default browser behaviour, which is to show the title attribute as a "tooltip" in the browser itself.

You'll need to resort to some javascript, it could even be as simple as setting the title to blank on hover, and replacing it on mouse out....

```
onmouseover="this.setAttribute('data-title', this.title);this.title = ''"
onmouseout="this.setAttribute('title', this.getAttribute('data-title')"
```

This will set the title to be blank (therefore "disabling" the tooltip), and store it in a data attribute. then on mouseout it will put the title back (meaning your semantic-ui stuff will still work).  You will need to integrate this at the correct point in your code of course.